# How to read audio file

Tags: java, android, audio, inputstream, outputstream

In an Android project I am reading an audio file into an `InputStream` and consequently write it to another location on the device. When reading, `in.read(buffer)` as shown in the snippet returns `-1`. After running the app, I locate the file using the phone's file manager app to play. But it doesn't play because the file is empty, i.e. size is `0 bytes`. What is the right way to read and write audio files in using `InputStreams` and `OutputStreams`?

```
try {
DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("audio/mp3", "New File");
OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/beat.mp3");
// To check whether the source file exists
File testFile = File("/storage/emulated/0/beat.mp3");
Log.d("App", "exists: " + testFile.exists() + " len: " + testFile.length());//exists: true len: 0
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.d("Exception ", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: avoid using hard-coded file system paths. Refer to this link https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers

Comment: @nandsito noted. But this is only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: You posted the same code again with all that saf stuff. I suggested you to only post code to read a file. Concentrate on the real problem.  I also dont see file.exists() and file.length(). THAT should have been in it. No saf.

Comment: So you should not have talked about copying a file to begin with. Only reading.

Comment: @greenapps I've updated it, I hope this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

to be pedantic, use:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/beat.mp3");
```

And just make sure the path is correct and the file exists. Other than that, from the info you gave, I cannot think of anything else

Comment: Thanks but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/beat.mp3");
File newFile = File("/storage/emulated/0/beat.mp3");
```

Seem your code have problem here, newFile.getUri() is called before it init?

Comment: this is only to check whether the source file being read from actually exists. The snippet has been updated to remove that confusion.